# How can I get Spring to fatally exit if an Error is propagated out of a remote call

Tags: java, spring, exception, rmi

I have an application which exposes a service via Spring's **RMI proxy** mechanism. There is a problem whereby sometimes a "blip" on the file-server it has its JARs stored on causes an invocation to propagate a `NoClassDefFoundError` back to the caller.

So far, so fair enough. The thing is, I would like my app to just crash if this happens - i.e. if an `Error` is going to be propagated back out to the caller.

Note that I already have an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in the app and this is not being invoked (because the exception is not really *uncaught*)

Comment: Do you want to bring down the whole server or just the particular app deployed on the server?

Comment: I want to bring down the server JVM. There's only one app on there ( it's not JEE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exposing the RMI service via `RmiServiceExporter` (or any other subclass of `RemoteExporter`), then you can [inject arbitrary interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/support/RemoteExporter.html#setInterceptors(java.lang.Object[])) into the call stack, which will be invoked whenever the RMI service is invoked.

These interceptors could trap any thrown `NoClassDefFoundError`, and call `System.exit()`.

For example:

```
public class ExitInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

 @Override
 public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
  try {
   return methodInvocation.proceed();
  } catch (NoClassDefFoundError noClassDefFoundError) {
   noClassDefFoundError.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(1);
   return null;
  }
 }

}
```

and

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
   <!-- existing properties -->
   <property name="interceptors">
      <bean class="com.x.ExitInterceptor"/>
   <property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to extend `[RmiServiceExporter][1]` and handle the exception in the `invoke` method. This can be done as so

```
public class AutoFailRmiServiceExporter extends RmiProxyFactoryBean implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext ac;
    @override
    public Object invoke(RemoteInvocation invocation,
                    Object targetObject)
             throws NoSuchMethodException,
                    IllegalAccessException,
                    InvocationTargetException {
        try {
          super.invoke(methodInvocation, target);
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
          if {ac instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
            (ConfigurableApplicationContext)ac).close();
          else {
            //log error
          }
        }
    }
    //application context setter

}
```

You would then use your AutoFail version of the RmiServiceExporterwhen defining your rmi service in your spring context.

**EDIT:** The original answer showed a way of killing the client when the exception is thrown. This is done by subclassing RmiProxyFactorty and overriding doInvoke instead of RmiServiceExporter.

Comment: `RmiProxyFactoryBean` is used on the client, not the server.

Comment: My answer assumes that you wanted to kill the client. From a second reading it appears that you want to kill the service app. The same principle still applies. Instead of extending RmiProxyFactory you would extend RmiServiceExporter

Comment: I want to kill the server: the point being is that my client will then failover to a secondary server instance